# Activity Bar width in Visual Studio Code

Tags: user-interface, ide, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to selectively change the width of the [Activity Bar in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface) (v. 1.14)? I have a 1366×768 screen where every pixel counts, so I would like to make this bar narrow and icons smaller, by at least 50%. In comparison to vertical OS interface elements, e.g. Windows 10 Taskbar or Plasma 5 panel it looks monstrous and out of place:

[image]

I've been also trying to find a solution for the Insider version of VSCode, but apart from just hiding it I haven't discovered anything relevant yet.

I have `"window.zoomLevel": 0` set in `settings.json`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**EDIT (03/03/20)**: You can also use the [customize-ui](https://github.com/iocave/customize-ui) addon that allows more fine-grained font sizes and other goodies

---

You can also use the negative zoom trick in `settings.json`:

```
{
  "window.zoomLevel": -1,
  "editor.fontSize": 13,
  "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 16,
}
```

The whole editor will get smaller so you need to compensate `editor.fontSize` and `terminal.integrated.fontSize`

[image: VSCode Zoom Level preview]

This allows for smaller **activity bar** (unfortunately it acts on everything (icons size, font-size ...)) but I much prefer this than the defaults.

Comment: FYI about that customize UI extension, is that in the reviews people note of it forcing a VS Code reinstall if attempting to use it with the later versions (after 1.73). I assume it will be fixed later, but I was forced to reinstall to fix my VS Code after attempting to use it. I'm currently on 1.77, which it doesn't work with that also.

Comment: readers might also want to take a look at https://github.com/drcika/apc-extension#apcactivitybar (I have no affiliation)

Answer (score 75):

I recommend the excellent extension [Activitus Bar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.activitusbar). It recreate the activity bar buttons on the status bar:

[image]

Then, you just hide this enormous, gigantic *activity bar*. Happying code!

Comment: very nice...but not respecting themes

Comment: the file change count goes away. No point in showing it all if it gives no visual meaning

Comment: This would have been nice as it takes up lesser space than Customize UI and integrates into the status bar. **But I don't recommend it because it can only show the five standard icons.** It doesn't show icons contributed by extensions. There's a setting to configure additional icons, but I need the extension to automatically pick up all icons! I can't be expected to configure and reconfigure it whenever I add/remove extensions.

Comment: Thanks, can't  believe  I'm so late to know this!

Answer (score 21):

Not solving your exact question but another good solution...

- Install the [Customize UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui) extension.
- In `Settings (UI)` go to the Customize UI settings and set `Activity Bar` to `"bottom"`.
- Completely close VSCode and reopen.

[image: sidebar on bottom of vscode]

Comment: this extension makes so much sense to me

Comment: FYI about that customize UI extension, is that in the reviews people note of it forcing a VS Code reinstall if attempting to use it with the later versions (after 1.73). I assume it will be fixed later, but I was forced to reinstall to fix my VS Code after attempting to use it. I'm currently on 1.77, which it doesn't work with that also.

Comment: As of Nov 2022, Customize UI doesn't work anymore ([#156](https://github.com/iocave/customize-ui/issues/156)), and there's some reports that trying to install it will break your VS Code ([#174](https://github.com/iocave/customize-ui/issues/174)).

Answer (score 7):

Not exactly what was asked, but instead of hiding it completely, I added a keyboard shortcut to be able to toggle the bar.

On macOS: `Code` > `Preferences` > `Keyboard shortcuts` > search for: `Toggle Activity Bar Visibility`

On Linux: `File` > `Preferences` > `Keyboard shortcuts` > search for: `Toggle Activity Bar Visibility`

Alternatively, you can get to `Keyboard shortcuts` by pressing `ctrl + k` and then `ctrl + s`.

I set it to `Option + B` just like `Command + B` for the Side Bar toggle and show it just when I need something there.

Comment: This is a good alternative for those who love keyboard shortcuts. I had to go with Ctrl-Alt-B as Alt-B is mapped to Git Blame over here and Ctrl-Shift-B is taken too. **Tip: Ctrl-B toggles the sidebar itself.**

Answer (score 5):

Wanted to add more to Akelian answer:

On Windows/Linux - File > Preferences > Settings
On macOS - Code > Preferences > Settings

```
{
  "window.zoomLevel": -1,
  "editor.fontSize": 13,
  "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 16,
  "workbench.activityBar.visible": false,
}
```

Setting `false` to "workbench.activityBar.visible" removes the sidebar completely

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who previously used the Customize UI extension which no longer works, there's now a replacement: [Apc Customize UI++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=drcika.apc-extension)

It provides a similar level of customization, allowing changes that VS Code otherwise doesn't allow.

With VS Code on Windows, VS Code must be run as administrator to enable this new extension, but once it's enabled VS Code can be run normally.

Comment: Confirmed this one works well.