# How to make visual studio code sidebar smaller without compromising the font size of the code inside the editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to make the icons(explorer, search, source control etc.)  on the left side of the code editors smaller in size. But when I do `command -` it reduces the size of the code's font within the editor too. How do I go about this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45048214/activity-bar-width-in-visual-studio-code and https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/52641 for a possible PR.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity Bar width in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45048214/activity-bar-width-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 8):

Currently, the only way I am aware of is what I do:

Click on `Preferences`, `Settings`, scroll down to `Editor: Font Size`, and change it from the default of `12` to `14` or `16`.

Then click `Command` + `-` and it will shrink all the fonts (and the file font too).  This is where making the file fonts bigger comes in—the file fonts will be back to "normal" when you shrink everything.